# Django Serialize ValueQuerySet

Tags: python, django, json

I'm new to Django and I'm running into issues trying to return a ValueQuerySet as a JSON.

Let's say I have a model:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to get the count of the Polls for a date so I use:

```
total = models.Poll.objects.extra({'date': "DATE(date)"}).values('date').annotate(total=Count('id'))
```

This gives a ValueQuerySet. I'd like to return this as a JSON response.

Here's my view:

```
def get_total(request):
    total= models.Poll.objects.extra({'date': "DATE(date)"}).values('date').annotate(total=Count('id'))
    for i in total: #Convert datetime.date object to string
        i['date'] = str(i['date'])
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(total), content_type='application/json')
```

I get this error:

```
[{'date': '2013-12-02', 'total': 1}, {'date': '2013-12-03', 'total': 2}] is not JSON serializable
```

Any advice on how to set this up would be appreciated. I'm also using Tastypie to set up an API. If this can be achieved using Tastypie that would great.

Comment: try `json.dumps(list(total))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert querysets to list to serialize them.
If you use the DjangoJSONEncoder you don't need to convert the dates your self.

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
def get_total(request):
    total= models.Poll.objects.extra({'date': "DATE(date)"}).values('date').annotate(total=Count('id'))
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(list(total), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder),content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. I tried using the DjangoJSONEncoder, but was missing the part to convert to a list.